# Apply diff role to different user in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, security-roles

How can i Apply diff role to different user with asp.net c#

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to the website tab and then in it ASP.NET configuration (now open your browser window which just popped up)
2. Then choose security option
3. Then setup wizard
4. After 3 steps you will be asked for giving role to particular user
5. Select role u want to apply
6. You are done

Answer (score 0):

First of all you provided no code sample or any details whatsoever. 
Anyway if you are reffering to ASP.NET apps you can use the 
ASP.NET default website administration tool to reach the goal you presented.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Actually I want basic information about how to start work on this. .so i provided no code. .thanks

Comment: Those are very different things, have you read the FAQ page on this site?